# How to I redirect back to my topics/show page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Hey all so in my code I am just redirecting back to the index of all the topics and theoretically I would like to redirect back to the page.
this is my controller for this page, right now I am just using `topics_path` as a stand in.

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
  def create
   @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:bookmark_id])
   like = current_user.likes.build(bookmark: @bookmark)
   if like.save
       flash[:notice] = "Successfully liked bookmark."
   else
     flash.now[:alert] = 'Error in liking bookmark. Please try again.'
   end
     redirect_to topics_path
 end

 def destroy
   @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:bookmark_id])
   like = current_user.likes.find(params[:id])
   # Get the bookmark from the params
   # Find the current user's like with the ID in the params

   if like.destroy
     flash[:notice] = "Successfully unliked bookmark."
   else
     flash.now[:alert] = 'Error in unliking bookmark. Please try again.'
   end
   redirect_to topics_path
 end
end
```

this is the line from rake routes that I was to `redirect_to`
`bookmarks_show GET    /bookmarks/show(.:format)                      bookmarks#show`

Comment: Can you share your `index` method in `TopicsController`

Comment: `def index`<br>
    `@topics = Topic.all`<br>
    `authorize(@topics)`<br>
  `end`<br>     I'm not sure why my markdown syntax is not working right.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to redirect back to a specific topic's page... then you'll need to pass the topic_id through as a param so you can use it in the redirection.

Add it into the form/link you're using eg:
(note: totally making this up, obviously your code will be different)

```
<% form_for @like do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :topic_id, @topic.id %>
```

Then in your create action, you just redirect using that eg:

```
 def create
   @bookmark = Bookmark.find(params[:bookmark_id])
   like = current_user.likes.build(bookmark: @bookmark)
   if like.save
     flash[:notice] = "Successfully liked bookmark."
   else
     flash.now[:alert] = 'Error in liking bookmark. Please try again.'
   end
   redirect_to topic_path(:id => params[:topic_id])
 end
```

Note: if you want to use some other page (eg the bookmark page) then use that instead... this is a "general howto" not a "use this code exactly as you see it here" :)